# How to convert a string to datetime in Sybase

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I have a **string** eg. "2008-01-01 11:09:11".

How do I convert this to a **datetime** ?

Comment: Do you have that string outside of Sybase and you want to know how to insert it as a datetime? Or do you have the string in Sybase and you want to return it as a datetime?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using it as a literal string in, say, a `SELECT` statement or a stored procedure call, the conversion is automatic.

If you've got it in a variable, `convert(datetime, @stringDateTime)` should work.

Comment: that's incorrect. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500703/what-is-the-mysterious-timestamp-datatype-in-sybase

Comment: @aF. No, the answer is correct.  The reference to TIMESTAMP is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

The timestamp datatype is defined as `varbinary(8) null` and does it have any relation at all to time or date.

**You cannot convert timestamp to datetime in sybase.**

Comment: That is not the question being asked.