# How to use TIMESTAMP option in sybase

Tags: database, timestamp, sybase

Hope all are doing great,

I want to create a table in sybase database and the table should have a column with current system time, So i plan to go with TIMESTAMP datatype.

But it not let me to create the table, tried with different way of declaring.

So please provide me a simple table creation with timestamp options..

(Note : i dont want to manually insert system time into the column while inserting, it should be auto update the column )
Tried with TIMESTAMP, Default timestamp, current timestamp,, everything i found by surfing..

so please suggest with any simple table creation query..

THanks in advance

Comment: Sybase was a company, not a database, and the answer to your question depends on which Sybase DB product you are using.  This question does a pretty good job of explaining timestamp for different Sybase DBs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500703/what-is-the-mysterious-timestamp-datatype-in-sybase

Answer (score 1):

According to me Curent Timestamp in Sybase is inserted using GETDATE() rahter than any other method.