# Create a timestamp from separate date and time integers

Tags: sybase, amos

I'm trying to create a from - to datetime range from fields in a database table.

Unfortunately the fields aren't saved as a timestamp.

I have two entries

- time in hours from midnight
- date in days from 1 jan 1970

Is there a command to combine these entries so i can use a select statement and search in a range of time?

My database is sybase 15.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried some options aswell, and this one seems to work for me:

```
CONVERT(
   VARCHAR,
   DATEADD(
      DAY,
      time_captured.end_date,
      `DEC 31 1971`
   ),
   104
) || `` || RIGHT(
   `00` || CONVERT(
      VARCHAR,
      FLOOR(time_captured.end_time/60)
   ),
   2
) || `:` || RIGHT(
   `00` + CONVERT(
      VARCHAR,
      time_captured.end_time%60
   ),
   2
) || `:00` >= CONVERT(
   VARCHAR,
   DATEADD(
      DAY,
      sp.start_date,
      `DEC 31 1971`
   ),
   104
) || `` || RIGHT(
   `00` || CONVERT(
      VARCHAR,
      FLOOR(sp.start_time/60)
   ),
   2
) || `:` || RIGHT(
   `00` + CONVERT(
      VARCHAR,
      sp.start_time%60
   ),
   2
) || `:00`
```

The way this database is made is quite weird. Thanks for all your answers!

Answer (score 0):

timestamp column type in Sybase is not ... about time and date (look at this [What is the mysterious 'timestamp' datatype in Sybase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500703/what-is-the-mysterious-timestamp-datatype-in-sybase)).

If you want to be able to filter records by datetime (combining date and time) here is what you should look at :

1. a column of type datetime in your table

You could also use the getdate() function of sybase to have default value recorded, as of :
    datetime_field DATETIME default getDate()

2. using 2 columns of type DATE and TIME you can combien then to obtain a DATETIME type which you can use for filtering your records.

For example:

```
# Casting into a DATETIME from DATE and TIME fields
CAST(date_field AS DATETIME) + CAST(time_field AS DATETIME)

# Filtering against DATETIME
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE datetime_field < CAST(date_field AS DATETIME) + CAST(time_field AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a manual conversion function that is translating some integer to datetime type you can write a UDF (user defined function) by yourself.

```
create function todatetime(@mydate int, @mytime int)
returns datetime
as
  declare @year int, @month int, @day, @hour int, @minute int, @second @int
  declare @datestring varchar(50)
  select @year = @mydate / 365 + 1970
  select @month = @mydate ...

  select @datestring = convert(varchar, @year + "-" + @month + ...
  return convert(datetime, @datestring)
go
```

Of course you have to add leap year support, etc., but is doable and it should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that your named these two columns `DaysSince1970` and `HoursSinceMidnight` ...

Then you can build an inferred `datetime` (not `timestamp`) using the expression

```
dateadd(hh,HoursSinceMidnight,dateadd(dd,DaysSince1970,'1-jan-1970'))
```

However, this a calculated column and is going to be **terrible** for indexed searches, so you will need some logic like.

```
DECLARE @DaysSince1970      int
,       @HoursSinceMidnight int
,       @SearchDateTime     datetime

SELECT  @DaysSince1970      = datediff(dd,'1-Jan-1970',@SearchDateTime)
,       @HoursSinceMidnight = datepart(hh,@SearchDateTime)

-- search your table
SELECT  *
FROM    tablename
WHERE   DaysSince1970       = @DaysSince1970
AND     HoursSinceMidnight  = @HoursSinceMidnight
```

Ideally your table will need and index on `DaysSince1970`, `HoursSinceMidnight`.

Finding rows in a range will be a simple extension of this, but remember that once you are checking across multiple days, don't check a range of 'raw' hours, just check the day range and then use the first method that I gave you to check the date/time range.