# MyBatis LocalDateTimeTypeHandler implementation depends on vendor conversion

Tags: java, jdbc, mybatis, sap-ase

My Environment:

- Java 8
- MyBatis 3.5.6
- SAP jConnect for JDBC 16.0 SP04 (note: 16.0 SP04 is now [JDBC4.2 compliant](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/12/11/whats-new-in-sap-ase-16.0-sp04/))

I have a problem on `LocalDateTimeHandler` with SAP jConnect.
Executing a SELECT statement for a `DATETIME` column with mapping to a `LocalDateTime` property causes a SQLException (caused by ClassCastException).

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.sybase.jdbc42.tds.SybTimestamp to java.time.LocalDateTime
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3369)
    at com.sybase.jdbc42.jdbc.SybResultSet.convertObjectToJavaType(SybResultSet.java:3665)
    at com.sybase.jdbc42.jdbc.SybResultSet.getObject(SybResultSet.java:3632)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.ResultSetLogger.invoke(ResultSetLogger.java:69)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy211.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.LocalDateTimeTypeHandler.getNullableResult(LocalDateTimeTypeHandler.java:38)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.LocalDateTimeTypeHandler.getNullableResult(LocalDateTimeTypeHandler.java:28)
    at org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.getResult(BaseTypeHandler.java:85)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getPropertyMappingValue(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:511)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.applyPropertyMappings(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:480)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getRowValue(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:404)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValuesForSimpleResultMap(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:354)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValues(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:328)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:301)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSets(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:194)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:65)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:79)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.ReuseExecutor.doQuery(ReuseExecutor.java:60)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:325)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:109)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:89)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:147)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:427)
    ... 54 more
```

The MyBatis [LocalDateTimeTypeHandler](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/mybatis-3.5.6/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/type/LocalDateTimeTypeHandler.java#L38) expects [ResultSet.getObject()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) to return a `LocalDateTime` object, but jConnect doesn't support it.
According to the javadoc and JDBC 4.2 specification for the `TIMESTAMP` column,
only `java.sql.Timestamp` type conversion must be supported at a minimum, but other type conversions (including `LocalDateTime`) are not expected to be supported by some vendors.

My Questions:

- Is this a bug of MyBatis ? or by design to support only some specific vendors ?
- Is there any workaround ?

##### Reference

- javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-
- JDBC API Spec 4.2: https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_2-mrel2-spec/index.html

  - TABLE B-3 Mapping from JDBC Types to Java Object Types

Comment: Are you sure you want to use [`TIMESTAMP`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3500703/1261766)? Last time I checked, the built-in `LocalDateTimeTypeHandler` worked for a `DATETIME` column.

Comment: Just to be clear, it is not a bug. JDBC 4.2 compliant drivers are expected to support `LocalDateTime` via `setObject()` and `getObject()`. See 
http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdbc-spec-discuss/2012-December/000010.html Besides, converting `LocalDateTime` to/from `java.sql.Timestamp` could generate [unexpected result](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/pull/1478#issuecomment-513266102) depending on the default time zone. In case your driver does not support the conversion, [here](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/pull/1478#issuecomment-512226734) is a workaround.

Comment: @ave The database column type I'm using is actually `DATETIME`. (I'll correct the question later). Could you please let me know the SAP ASE version and edition in your environment which works for you ? I will check my env if there are something wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused, it seems. I re-tested using jconn4.jar bundled with SAP ASE 16 SP03 and the driver does not support `LocalDateTime` indeed.  You should report the issue to SAP. Until they fix it, you  may have to use the workaround I mentioned. The old implementations may work fine if your system runs on a time zone that does not have DST.

Comment: @ave Thank you for the info. Just for your information, jconn4.jar is a JDBC4.0 compliant implementation. The jconn4.jar has the `ResultSet.getObject()` but as an abstract method so that `LocalDateTimeTypeHandler` cannot call it. The jconn42.jar is a JDBC4.2 compliant provided by ASE 16 SP04.

Comment: Here are some more details https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/1644